# Flutter preview equivalent to test widgets independently in vs code or android studio

Tags: flutter, android-studio, visual-studio-code

I am looking for a Preview (XCode) equivalent for Flutter either in VS Code or Android Studio. My objective is to be able to debug UI in a decoupled manner, for example if I code a widget, I would like to be able to preview it in isolation.

I have created some test code but its not responsive or hot-reloads.

[image]

Comment: Hot-reload should update in realtime whenever you save changes to a widget. I don't believe you can isolate widgets and display only a given widget like you're asking, but hot-reload should allow you to test it in realtime.